# Parse ServerUrl gives me 404 error on the JS Client

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm moving my app to my own server and everything is working wonderful except one little problem: I added the Server URL to the JS like this:

```
Parse.initialize("0B5jvlihE6yxQed1w9vRSRW0DRldy3fbwqaCjpyF", "mJid6m5wPuWICUNhqm6KrG83pWudt2Y3pumEiaY2");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://www.jobninja.eu:1337/parse'
```

And everything is ok **BUT**, it makes request like this:

> curl 'http://www.jobninja.eu:1337/parse/1/classes/Category' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://0.0.0.0:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://0.0.0.0:8080/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"where":{},"order":"title","_method":"GET","_ApplicationId":"0B5jvlihE6yxQed1w9vRSRW0DRldy3fbwqaCjpyF","_JavaScriptKey":"mJid6m5wPuWICUNhqm6KrG83pWudt2Y3pumEiaY2","_ClientVersion":"js1.6.7","_InstallationId":"be5bdfe1-ed0c-60bf-0d49-c5fcfdefad29"}' --compressed

And my Parse server do not understand these ones but understands very well these ones:

> curl 'http://www.jobninja.eu:1337/parse/classes/Category' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://0.0.0.0:8080' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://0.0.0.0:8080/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"where":{},"order":"title","_method":"GET","_ApplicationId":"0B5jvlihE6yxQed1w9vRSRW0DRldy3fbwqaCjpyF","_JavaScriptKey":"mJid6m5wPuWICUNhqm6KrG83pWudt2Y3pumEiaY2","_ClientVersion":"js1.6.7","_InstallationId":"be5bdfe1-ed0c-60bf-0d49-c5fcfdefad29"}' --compressed

The only difference between the two requests is that on the second one, I removed the `/1/` in the URL.

**Do you know what I missed in the JS part which leads to this error?**

Btw, I upgraded JSParseSDK to the latest version and tried the version with and without slash in the `serverUrl` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the /parse/1

I think you had use parse server example as reference, and it mounts parse API in /parse (and not /parse/1). Therefore you have to change all your requests to /parse or change your parse server to mount parse api in /parse/1

Comment: I also have this problem @davi-macêdo can you clarify a little bit for me how to get rid of the /1 ?

Comment: If you are using Parse Server to run your backend instead of parse.com, you have not to use /1/ anymore in your requests. For example, instead of https://yourdomain.com/parse/1/classes/MyObject use only https://yourdomain.com/parse/classes/MyObject

Answer (score 0):

the client key is not required, The javascript can work without it, also you are missing a semicolon after the serverURL... This doesnt seem like problem with Javascript but with your server, check the index.js on the server

Comment: Nope, I got the bug, it is the parse sdk I used was a unmaintained fork on Bower

Answer (score 0):

The client key is no longer needed when using the parse-server

Client code :

```
//Initialize my Local Host App
Parse.initialize("app");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';
```

Server code :

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'app',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'master', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was using an old version of the parse.com code.
Apparently the version at http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.13.min.js automatically appends the /1/ to the url you give it. Changing it to use version 1.6.14 (the version recommended at https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/existing) fixed the problem.